# How to override global context using Provider in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state-management, react-state-management, react-context

I have run into an issue where I need to somehow hijack/override a global status passed to one single child component, while keeping the global status itself untouched because other child components are depending on it. Just wondering whether such override is doable by nesting Provider with values prop, because I think the `useContext` hook will look for the nearest provider?

This is my status context hook:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const StatusContext = React.createContext([{ disabled: false }, () => {}]);
const StatusProvider = props => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState({ disabled: false });
  return (
    <StatusContext.Provider value={[status, setStatus]}>
      {props.children}
    </StatusContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { StatusContext, StatusProvider };
```

And I intend to use it like this:

```
<StatusProvider>
  <ChildComponent1 name={"ChildComponent1"} label={"ChildComponent1"} />
  <ChildComponent3 name={"ChildComponent3"} label={"ChildComponent3"} />
</StatusProvider>
<StatusProvider>
  <ChildComponent2 name={"ChildComponent2"} label={"ChildComponent2"} />
</StatusProvider>
```

I want to change the context for ChildComponent3.
Because all child components in their implementation are relying on this global status context, I can't simply change the status. Therefore, I am looking at overriding the state by providing default values at Provider like this:

```
<StatusProvider>
  <ChildComponent1 name={"ChildComponent1"} label={"ChildComponent1"} />
  <StatusProvider value={someOverrideValue}>
    <ChildComponent3 name={"ChildComponent3"} label={"ChildComponent3"} />
  </StatusProvider>
</StatusProvider>
```

But no matter what values I tried to pass it in, it doesn't seem to work.
So is it doable by nesting the Provider and proving values? if so, what should I pass in?

Much appreciated!

A simple codesandbox is provided: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-platform-ntizj

Comment: Of course it is possible. From the react docs: `Providers can be nested to override values deeper within the tree.` You are doing something wrong. Maybe show how the components are reading the context. Also might want to write a new Provider for the override instead of reusing the original.

Comment: Hi @morganney Thanks for the reply! I just added a sandbox link! Do you mind having a look?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant for you, but your `useContext` instances were not destructuring the `value` from the context, you were pulling those into an array:

```js
const [status] = useContext(StatusContext);
```

vs.

```js
const { status } = useContext(StatusContext);
```

Also, your nested Provider override had a `value` prop that was not being consumed/used by the Provider to set the Context value. Here’s the working version:

```js
const StatusProvider = ({ children, disabled = false }) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState({ disabled });
  return (
    <StatusContext.Provider value={{status, setStatus}}>
      {children}
    </StatusContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I modified your sandbox link with the working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-sara-z2cldn?file=/src/App.jsx

Thanks for putting that together, it helped me confirm a similar scenario that I am currently troubleshooting.